# The good way to cascade creation / removing collection in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is the right way to make several removal of collection the first or the second one ?

I feel that it is the second one but the first one is more easy to use. Is it possible to use promise to ease the read of the code?

First way:

```
beforeEach((done) => { 
    //Before each test we empty the database

    //Remove Roles
    Role.remove({}, (err) => {});

    //Remove Users
    User.remove({}, (err) => {});

    // Remove Workouts
    Workout.remove({}, (err) => {});

    // Create user
    Role.create({"name" : "Administrator"},(err, adminRole) => {
        User.create({ firstname : "***", businessId: "1", lastname : "***", email : "***", roles:[adminRole]}, (err) => { 
            done();             
        });
    });
});`
```

Second way:

```
beforeEach((done) => { 
    //Before each test we empty the database

    //Remove Roles
    Role.remove({}, (err) => {
        //Remove Users
        User.remove({}, (err) => {
            // Remove Workouts
            Workout.remove({}, (err) => {
                // Create user
                Role.create({"name" : "Administrator"},(err, adminRole) => {
                    User.create({ firstname : "***", businessId: "1", lastname : "***", email : "***", roles:[adminRole]}, (err) => { 
                        done();             
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The second option is the safest one, because if an error happens in a operation, the next ones are not executed.

And sure you should use promises. The code becomes way cleaner:

```
Role.remove({})
  .then(() => User.remove({})
  .then(() => Workout.remove({})
  .then(() => Role.create({"name" : "Administrator"})
  .then((adminRole) => User.create({ firstname : "***", businessId: "1", lastname : "***", email : "***", roles:[adminRole]})
  .then(() => done())
  .catch((error) => ...);
```

To be able to use promises, you can set the `promise` of mongoose to be the native one (as long as your node version is >= 6):

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Comment: Thank you Alberto. Indeed, your proposition with Promise is more sexy :-). First question: if User.remove({}) fails, Workout.remove({}) will not be executed ?

Comment: @oliviercherrier Yes, exactly. If `User.remove({})` fails, it goes straight to to `catch`

Comment: Second question: What about the asynchronous with first way ? Does Workout .remove be execute since User.remove() ended or can it be executed before User.remove ended ?

Comment: It would be executed independently of User.remove() result

Comment: Glad to help :)